# Graph API to control Identity Protection Policies

Tags: security, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for the Graph API endpoint to view and manage Azure AD Identity Protection Policies. I have managed to deal with Conditional access policies. But still wondering whether it is possible to control Sign In Risk policies and User risk Policies with Graph API. Appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: You could improve this question by adding some more details like code you have tried or maybe screenshots from the service you are asking about.

Comment: please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-graph-api and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/best-practices-concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Graph API to control Sign In Risk policies and User risk Policies.

There are three APIs that expose information about risky users and sign-ins:

The first API, [riskDetection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/riskdetection?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0), allows you to query Microsoft Graph for a list of both user and sign-in linked risk detections and associated information about the detection.

The second API, [riskyUsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/riskyuser?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0), allows you to query Microsoft Graph for information about users Identity Protection detected as risk.

The third API, [signIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signin?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0), allows you to query Microsoft Graph for information on Azure AD sign-ins with specific properties related to risk state, detail, and level.

For more detailed information, please refer to:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-graph-api).

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, can you accept it as an answer?( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.